# How to save image path into database in Laravel?

Tags: php, image, laravel, laravel-5

I want to upload an image and retrieve in from database when i need this.My code is perfectly working to upload image but it's path did not save in database.In database it's showing `Null`.Here is my code:

```
    if ($request->hasFile('profilePic')) {
        $file = array('profilePic' => Input::file('profilePic'));
        $destinationPath = 'img/'; // upload path
        $extension = Input::file('profilePic')->getClientOriginalExtension(); 
        $fileName = rand(11111,99999).'.'.$extension; // renaming image
        Input::file('profilePic')->move($destinationPath, $fileName);
    }else{
        echo "Please Upload Your Profile Image!";
    }
    $profile->save();
```

**My Question:**

- How to save image path into database?
- And how to retrieve image from database?

**Updated: Profile.php**

```
class Profile extends Model
{
    protected $table = "profiles";
    public $fillable = ["firstName","lastName","middleName","DOB","gender","featuredProfile","email","phone","summary","profilePic"];
}
```

Comment: Can you post your profile model file? Can't you just use something like $profile->image_location = $destinationPath . '/' . $filename;

Comment: @Brett I have updated my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code there should be like this:

```
$profile->profilePic = $fileName;
```

& then

```
$profile->save();
```

Answer (score 1):

**1.How to save image path into database?**

To save your full image path in a database field, the code is:

```
$profile->profilePic = $destinationPath.$fileName;
$profile->save();
```

**2.And how to retrieve image from database?**

In your view file using blade engine, write HTML code like this. In the image src you have to provide profilePic data as shown in the below HTML code:

```
<img src="{{asset($profile->profilePic)}}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$path = $file->getRealPath();;
    $pos = strpos($path,'/public/');
    if ($pos !== false) {
        $path = substr($path, $pos + 1);
    }
    $input['file'] = $path;
```